# How can I pick same time of day across multiple days?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, datetime

Column `utc time created` is a `datetime` field of when entry was made in a table that's updated hourly. Contains 24 entries for each day.

I want to query for same time of day across a set of days (might want all 4pm records for 10/1-10/10) but don't want records for other times in that date range. I don't want *all* 4pm records in the table (the whole month is in the table).

How to do this for both SQLite and MySQL?

Comment: Do u have some sample query. Have u tried googling, stackoverflowing.

Comment: 4p utc?  or some other timezone?  (I'm assuming your "utc time created" actually stores utc times?)  and by 4p, do you mean exactly, or just in that hour?

Comment: @ysth  yes it stores utc times and 4pm in that same timezone. and yes just the 4pm exactly. not 3:59pm or anything sooner,  not 4:01pm or anything latter  just 4pm

Comment: @user4157124 I'm currently using sqlite via c# and when I used that data type in a create table statement it had no issue, and when i loaded data into the table as if was that datatype it did not complain. then when I downloaded the sqlite database browser it shows the proper time and date in there for all the records i compared. so it seems to be working now.

Comment: Yes, in SQLite datatype names from traditional SQL implementations are [converted into affinities](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_name_examples).

Comment: There is no datetime data type in SQLite. You can use it but this does not mean that SQLite will treat it as such. If you store values like `2022-10-13 04:55:00 pm` this is just a string for SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Just filter by date and then hour:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    TableName
WHERE 
    CAST(UTCTimeCreated AS DATE) BETWEEN '2022-10-01' AND '2022-10-10'
    AND HOUR(UTCTimeCreated) = 16 -- or whatever
```

Comment: And for the SQL folks since both sql and mysql is tagged: DATEPART(hour, UTCTimeCreated) = 16

Comment: @AnthonyG. sql is a general tag; are you thinking of the sql-server tag?

Comment: Just mentioning that HOUR is mySQL while DATEPART is MS SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what John K. have (SQL):

```
    SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    TableName
WHERE 
    UTCTimeCreated BETWEEN '2022-10-01' AND '2022-10-10' AND DATEPART(Hour,UTCTimeCreated ) = 16
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this portably between sqlite and mysql, you can use substr.

```
select *
from foo
where
    utc_created_time >= '2022-10-01' and
    utc_created_time < '2022-10-14' and
    substr(utc_created_time,12,8)='16:00:00'
```

Avoid `between` if you might be looking for midnight times; `datetime between date and date` behaves differently between mysql and sqlite.  So just do `<` the day after your end date.